# Why long running threads cause cpu overhead?

Tags: iis, cpu, cpu-usage

Recently in our production environment, one of our web site which is running at IIs caused 100% CPU usage.

We figured out that issue was about long running MySQL queries. I know that the ASP.NET engine uses thread pool for processing HTTP requests and when I got a dump file for the worker process, thread count was about 100~. I can't really understand why long running DB queries cause CPU overhead. If anyone can explain with details I'll be glad.

Comment: Try posting the task manager screenshot and see which process is actually taking more CPU and memory

Comment: Sounds like thrashing to me. Thread 1 does a little bit of work, then a context switch to thread 2, etc. Enough threads, and you're spending 90% on context switches and paging, and 10% on getting actual work done.